# for what values of $x$ does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin(x/2^n)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I can't seem to use the root or ratio test here because of the ugly function inside of $\sin(x)$. Have tried rewriting the function using the sin taylor series but again just end up with a long mess!

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In that case For all $x$. Note that  $|\sin\frac x{2^n}|\le \frac{|x|}{2^n}$

Comment: Actually you can use the ratio test.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown how?

Comment: You could resort to L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $|\sin(t)| \le |t|$ for real $t$.

Comment: so then the absolute sum of sin(x/(2^n)) ≤ absolute sum of x/(2^n) which converges hence our series converges. How do I find out for specific values of x?

Answer (score 0):

For all real $x$, There is some $N_0$ such that $|2^{-N_0} x| < 1.

Then
$$
\left| \sum_{N_0}^\infty \sin (2^{-n}x)  \right| \leq \left| \sum_{N_0}^\infty 2^{-N_0} x 2^{-(n-N_0)}  \right| \leq 2  
$$
So the infinite part of the series converges.  The remaining terms, with $n<N_0$, are a finite series, so of course that converges as well.

So $\sum_{N_0}^\infty \sin (2^{-n}x)  $ converges absolutely for all real $x$.

Comment: Please explain the last two inequalities